# 1 statement insert, but 2 records inserted

Tags: mysql, insert

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
TRUNCATE `postcode`;
INSERT INTO `postcode` (PostalCode, Name, State_id, country_id) VALUE('OTH',   'OTHERS', (SELECT id FROM `state` WHERE `code` = 'OTH'), (SELECT id FROM `country` WHERE `code` = 'OTH'));
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

I ran the script in MYSQL Uuery Browser. I chose new script tab. I clicked execute. I gave me 2 records in database. Why? I have no idea

I even step it line by line. still the same

Thank You

Comment: Perhaps you ran the statement twice.

Comment: Can you provide the data you used and the resulting rows? Or even just a sample?